# Windows Command Prompt CMD Close

Tags: python, windows, cmd

[image: cmd]

In Python, How can I check and close such cmd windows like in picture? This code should control and find which cmd is finished and idle like in picture, then close it. I don't want a code which is waiting to close it. It should be a detached program. By the way, the image is a sample. It is not my original problem.

You can think that you have a window or several windows opened and waiting like this, how can they be closed? There is a condition to close a command prompt. This condition is that program on that prompt should be done. Command prompts on which a program runs should not be closed. Moreover, this program should intervene externally and afterwards.

I can't solve with taskkill or psutil. They always see the state of cmd as running. More specifically, you can look at code snippet below,

```
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k python helloworld.py & exit")
```

It doesn't close the command prompt.

Comment: drag and drop the python file on the command prompt then it will show your output. after then type `exit` or `exit()` to close cmd

Comment: Why are you using both `start` and `cmd` twice?? `cmd /C python helloworld.py` (or `start "" /B cmd /C python helloworld.py`) should be enough…

Comment: @aschipfl I use it like that, because that way, it can start externally in a prompt and the program doesn't wait the prompt to be done. Otherwise, the program waits the prompt to be done and close it, which is that I don't want.

Comment: The simple solution is not using `os.system()` at all as the used code results in executing `%ComSpec% /c start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k python helloworld.py & exit` which means running `cmd.exe` to use its internal command `start` to run one more command process to use the internal command `start` to run one more command process to run `python.exe` for processing a Python script. `& exit` at end of this command line is interpreted by first `cmd.exe` started by `os.system` as command to execute after first `start`. The entire approach does not make sense.

Comment: The second cmd process is started with the command line `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe  /K start  cmd.exe @cmd /k python helloworld.py` which keeps running until a user enters `exit` because of option `/K`. The third command process is started with the command line `cmd.exe  @cmd /k python helloworld.py` which results in running `python.exe` with `helloworld.py` as argument and keeps running after `python.exe` terminated itself because of option `/k`. So the user has to enter `exit` to close third `cmd.exe` while first `cmd.exe` closed itself already after start of second `cmd.exe` because ...

Comment: ... of option `/c` and command `exit` at end of the command line. Hint: This can be all seen on using free Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with an include filter added for __Process Name is cmd.exe__ and pressing Ctrl+P or double click on each started `cmd.exe` process identified by its __PID__ (process identifier) and selecting in opened __Event Properties__ window the second tab __Process__ where the __Command Line__ is displayed used to start the process.

Comment: The Python documentation for [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) obviously not read carefully enough by you if read at all recommends to use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). The `subprocess` module supports running an executable like `python.exe` directly without using `cmd.exe` without or with opening a (console or graphic) window and without or with waiting for termination of started executable. Hint: Read about [sys.executable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) and make use of it to run `python.exe`.

Comment: The documentation of the `subprocess` module is easier to understand on having read carefully and completely the Microsoft documentations for function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and the structure [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) which are used by __all__ applications on Windows which can start an executable, independent on what is the name of the command/function in the programming/scripting language.

Comment: @Mofi. Thank you for your comments. This code does what exactly I want except closing. I have tried subprocess but from which I couldn't find get what exactly I want. Maybe I should review docs more carefully.

Comment: you use `cmd /k` to **k**eep the window open and complain about the window staying open?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're looking for this solution, but you can add "& exit" after your script, and that will close CMD.

For example:

```
python script.py & exit
```